# JdbcTemplate: accessing MySQL VARBINARY field as String

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm having trouble reading MySQL's **VARBINARY** field as a String using *JdbcTemplate*. We're storing string abbreviations ("ABC", "XYZ", "LMN" and the like) as VARBINARYs (don't ask me why). Strangely enough, when I use the Connection class / PreparedStatement route, and plain old ResultSets vs. SqlRowSet, I have no problem reading the String. That is to say,

This code works:

```
String sql = "select MY_VARBINARY_FIELD from MY_TABLE where KEY1=? and KEY2=?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connectionDev.prepareStatement(sql);
prepStmt1.setInt(1, key1);
prepStmt1.setInt(2, key2);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    String s = rs.getString("MY_VARBINARY_FIELD");
    System.out.print(s + " ");
}

**Output:** AHI-1 DKFZp686J1653 FLJ14023 FLJ20069 JBTS3 ORF1 dJ71N10.1
```

But this code doesn't:

```
String sql = "select MY_VARBINARY_FIELD from MY_TABLE where KEY1=? and KEY2=?";
Object[] params = {key1, key2};
SqlRowSet rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryForRowSet(sql, params);

while (rows.next()) {
    String s = rows.getString("MY_VARBINARY_FIELD");
    System.out.print(s + " ");
}

**Output:** [B@3a329572 [B@4ef18d37 [B@546e3e5e [B@11c0b8a0 [B@399197b [B@3857dc15 [B@10320399
```

Why do SqlRowSet and ResultSet produce a different String representation for the VARBINARY? And how can I get the "correct" representation using JdbcTemplate/SqlRowSet?

Thanks!

**SOLUTION**

Mark Rotteveel (below) answered the question. I got it to work with this:

```
String sql = "select MY_VARBINARY from MY_TABLE where KEY=VALUE";

SqlRowSet rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryForRowSet(sql);

while (rows.next()) {
     byte[] varbinary = (byte[]) rows.getObject("MY_VARBINARY");
     System.out.println(new String(varbinary));
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `[B@3a329572` etc is the result of a `toString()` on a byte array. A `VARBINARY` is represented using a `byte[]` in JDBC. Most likely when you access it directly on `PreparedStatement`, the driver does `new String(getBytes(idx))`, while the JdbcTemplate probably does a `getObject(idx).toString()` instead, resulting in output like `[B@3a329572`.

So to fix this, do a `getBytes()` on the JdbcTemplate, and convert it to string yourself or (better yet), use the byte array directly *or* change the column datatype to a VARCHAR instead.

Comment: +1 good spot. Also, probably a good idea to specify the character encoding to avoid cross-platform weirdness

Comment: @artbristol True, but I suspect the driver is also doing it without explicit characterset.

Comment: +1 This makes a lot of sense and you're probably right. I'll check later today.

Answer (score 0):

If I use that like below, it is good.

- org.mybatis 3.2.8
- mysql-connector-java 5.1.38 || mariadb-connector-java
- Java Bean , private String myVarbinary;

`my_varbinary(64)`  is for `SessionID` / `NameOfEnglis`h so that I don't need to consider `character_set` and encoding/decoding.